# Gunicorn: HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.'

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, gunicorn, foreman

I've deployed a few django projects to heroku and can't figure out at all what is going on here or where to start debugging. It seems to immediately crash.

```
foreman start
```

gives me:

```
00:13:21 web.1  | started with pid 1242
00:13:22 web.1  | exited with code 3
00:13:22 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

Procfile:
    `web: gunicorn lvngd.wsgi:application`

It crashes immediately when I push to heroku as well.

I don't even know where to start...I tried to start a different app, going through the django tutorial exactly to try to back track, but I got the same errors, so it seems like it's something in my setup?

The only difference between the apps I have previously deployed were that they were Django 1.5 and I am currently trying to push Django 1.6.

I've tried reinstalling the heroku toolbelt, reinstalling foreman, reinstalling gunicorn(gunicorn seems to work with python manage.py run_gunicorn) and checking settings, etc.

When I try to run `gunicorn lvngd.wsgi:application` I get a trace error and then `gunicorn.errors.HaltServer:`  but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: This looks like a bug in your django app somewhere, because H10 means the dyno crashed, and error code 3 usually indicates that a file or path is invalid. I hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I started a fresh django app(a blank one with nothing in it) and just tried to follow the heroku start-up guide, just so I could get something running, and it still gave me the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

The “official” answer I've gotten back from Heroku:

> This looks to be an issue with Gevent. I would recommend the following.
>
> - Ensure you have the latest version of Gevent installed.
> - Ensure you have the latest version of Gunicorn installed.
>
> If both of these are true, you may want to try using Eventlet. It's often more compatible with application code.

While I've done that I also added monitoring via Librato and Slack to notify me if the app starts responding poorly. When it does I issue a `heroku restart` command that rolls the running dynos over and appears to resolve this issue.